# Preserving Whitespace and Newline in Antlr4

Tags: c, antlr, antlr4

I want to preserve the Whitespaces and Newline characters for handling C source files, and I am using the grammar as mentioned [here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/c/C.g4).

I am modifying the lines form [here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/c/C.g4#L880) as follows, by removing the redirection to skip.

```
Whitespace
    :   [ \t]+
    ;

Newline
    :   (   '\r' '\n'?
        |   '\n'
        )
   ;
```

But while executing the parser on any C program, say the following:

```
void main(){
}
```

It is throwing an error

```
line 1:13 mismatched input '\n' expecting <EOF>
```

Any help to solve this problem would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Netter to post relevant information here.  Links die

Comment: You should post at least a minimal grammar which shows the fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot work. If you don't skip whitespaces (or at least put them on a different channel) they will be returned to the parser and have to be considered there. Since you only changed the lexer rules, but not the parser rules, nothing really can be matched. So the `translationUnit?` in

```
compilationUnit
    :   translationUnit? EOF
    ;
```

is simply skipped and EOF is expected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am wondering if there are any other ways to preserve the newline and whitespace characters.

Comment: As I wrote, you can put them on a different than the default channel and use the token stream to retrieve them later without having to deal with them during the parsing phase.